# How to convert bash script language to java

Tags: java, bash

I would like a script to execute upon ticking preference on an android phone. The toggle is done, but for now it executes this:

```
   if (preference == mRandomizeMac) {
         SystemProperties.set(RANDOMIZE_MAC_PERSIST_PROP, (Boolean) newValue ? "1" : "0");
```

Instead of set system properties, I would like to have the following script executed:

```
macaddr="$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=1 2>/dev/null|md5sum|sed 's/^\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\).*$/\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6/')"
echo $macaddr > /sys/devices/fb000000.qcom,wcnss-wlan/wcnss_mac_addr
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant `Java` and not `javascript`, due to the syntax of your example.

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)` to execute a shell command. Try passing your command into that method. If this doesn't work, you could try passing a `String[]` with the structure `["/bin/sh", "-c", **command**]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I am not a programmer, but rather a self-taught amateur. I can properly implement a commit, resolve conflicts, respond to an error, but I can't create language. So, I would appreciate if you can show me detailed examples of the two methods you mentioned. I want to pass that script in a .java file...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Allow me to explain it this way. You can't "convert" your bash script to Java. What you CAN do is execute shell commands from your Java code. Your bash script is just a fancy way of executing shell commands. So, you'll want to do research on how to execute shell commands from Java (using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` call) and get the output of those commands. I can't do all of your research for you, but I can give you some pointers on where to get started.

Comment: I did implement Runtime.getRuntime...  Now, the compiler does not like parenthesis in the actual shell script: illegal escape character:                                                                                                                    echo $(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=1 2>/dev/null|md5sum|sed 's/^\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\).*$/\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6/')"});
                                                                                                                        I am talking parenthesis over ..\

Comment: I'm not experienced enough with bash syntax to make any helpful comments on that. I can say a hacky (albeit functional) solution would be to write the bash script to a file, and execute the file using `sh filename` through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`, and delete the file afterwards.

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to do is to randomize wifi mac address on a Sony android phone. Sony is different in terms that it puts the address in a specific file in /sys/devices..... .  Is there a different way (other than bash script) to transmit the randomizing string into that specific file?

Comment: Absolutely, you can use a `FileOutputStream` to write data into a file.